# How to use Case-When in another Case-When Condition in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

when execute the following SQL in Oracle

```
  SELECT (CASE
            WHEN (CASE
                    WHEN (1=1)
                      THEN (1=1)
                    ELSE (1=0) 
                  END) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END) "m1"
  FROM "mock_table_1" "t0";
```

it will throw the following error message

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

So what should I do if I want to use Case-When in another Case-When Condition?

Comment: In `Then` and `Else` part you cannot evaluate expressions you need to place the result expression that is the problem in your query

Answer (score 0):

(You can omit the parentheses ) FROM DUAL is just for test

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN  CASE 
                   WHEN 1=1 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 
                   END =1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END "m1"
  FROM DUAL;
```

CASE returns a value.  So after END you can do your next condition